# Is spoofing attack possible in RS232 communication?

Tags: security, serial-port, spoofing, serial-communication

I am a rookie in network security field. I am eager to know if it is possible for a spoofing attack on a serial communication like RS232?

Comment: The question makes no sense. RS232 is a physical medium. Do you mean that the spoofer would falsely claim to be connected to the cable?

Comment: You could MITM it by cutting and splicing...

Answer (score 0):

The notion of spoofing data for a real serial port is kinda funny, hard to spoof anything when you can see the opposite end of the cable.  Still, serial ports made a comeback of sorts, lots of device drivers emulate a virtual serial port to make it easy for user-mode code to interface with them.  Including drivers for things like BlueTooth, hard to see the other end of the cable then.

And yes, spoofing is trivial if you can replace the device driver.  Luckily, replacing the device driver isn't trivial.  In general, any machine that's insecure enough to allow drivers to be replaced is wide-open for any kind of attack, not just through a serial port.